# put validation on page item through Dynamic Action

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

[image]

In this page I have put plsql code on click of Create Assignment button. There is a constraint on column "Assigned To" which usualy fires when that field left blank.

I want to put a validation so that I can get my own alert message which should be user readable. Also after that message submit process should be ignored.

I tried with field name :P11_Assignment NULL in the condition of PLSQL code in Dynamic Action but it is not working.

Please advise with a solution.

Comment: The behaviour you're describing isn't really suitable for the web-based world. Near client-side validation is standard behaviour in recent versions of APEX.

Comment: Are you sure you put `:P11_Assignment NOT NULL` ?because it's wrong and you should check for `:P11_Assignment IS NULL` I believe.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 yeah but even though it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Before the PL/SQL Action add an Execute Javascript action.

You will want to use apex.message.* function like the following:

```
apex.message.clearErrors
apex.message.showErrors
```

[Oracle Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/apex-message-namespace.htm)

Example:

```
apex.message.clearErrors();

if ($v("P11_Assignment").trim() == '') {
    apex.message.showErrors({
        type:       "error",
        location:   [ "page", "inline" ],
        pageItem:   "P11_Assignment",
        message:    'Must have a Value',
        unsafe:     false
    });
    return false; /* This is important, it stops the next action(s) from running. */
}
```

Comment: Entire Dynamic Action stopped working after this JS on button clink just before PLSQL Action

Comment: return false; stops the actions processing. BTW, if you put a console.log('msg') in the javascript, then use your browser console log and it will give you the ability to view the code in your browser and you can put a break-point in the code. You can then experiment with what is going on. e.g run $v("P11_Assignment") to see what you get etc.

Comment: Also, what is the identification name, please verify - by default these are often uppercase, e.g. perhaps it should be: $v("P11_ASSIGNMENT") or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

putting IF ELSE condition in the begining of plsql code
IF field is empty THEN don't execute the plsql code and change the field item to a value.

On value change of that item put an alert message in Dynamic Action.